# formatting External HDD gets stuck

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, ext4, formatting

I have an external 2TB HDD that i plan on leaving attached to my ubuntu server. I am trying to format it to ext4 but am encounterin issue

My current setup is a 200gb ssd in the server (sdb), 2x2TB HDD's that are Raid0 (sdc,sdd), and the external hdd i'm trying to format (sda)

```
ubnt@ubnt:~$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
[sudo] password for ubnt:
NAME              FSTYPE              SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda                                   1.8T
sdb                                 111.8G
├─sdb1            ext4                976M /boot
├─sdb2                                  1K
└─sdb5            LVM2_member       110.9G
  ├─ubnt--vg-root ext4              103.2G /
  └─ubnt--vg-swap swap                7.6G [SWAP]
sdc               linux_raid_member   1.8T            ubnt:0
└─md0             ext4                3.7T /mnt/md0
sdd               linux_raid_member   1.8T            ubnt:0
└─md0             ext4                3.7T /mnt/md0
```

When i try to create the ext4 file system on the hdd it gets stuck for ages at "Writing superblock... 730/14905" (always at the same number) and then gives an error:

```
ubnt@ubnt:~$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/sda
mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Found a dos partition table in /dev/sda
Creating filesystem with 488378112 4k blocks and 122101760 inodes
Filesystem UUID: bcca6fda-7429-41c2-9cba-31705fe1d791
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968,
        102400000, 214990848

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (262144 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information:   730/14905
Warning, had trouble writing out superblocks.
```

I tried `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda` but it gave no errors.

What can i do to make this disc usable?

Comment: Delete all the partition with fdisk and try. if still fails please check disk it may have bad sectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason this solved it (not entirely sure why now cause i'm sure i had done this. maybe a restart helped it:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda
n
p
*defaults. Press enter all the way through*
w
```

That created sda1 under sda, so i followed with

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/sda1
```